# Can I get some examples about not using isSome, SOME, NONE, null, but pattern checking?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I have learned that there is no need to use the isSome function, SOME, or NONE constructor if we know pattern checking, but I don't understand that concept.

So can I get some examples about not using isSome, SOME, NONE, null, but pattern checking?

Answer (score 1):

Using pattern matching, it is possible to reimplement these functions.  For example, `isSome` would look like this:

```
fun isSome NONE = false
  | isSome _ = true
```

Almost all the time, it is more convenient to use an inline `case` expression to examine such values, rather than calling such tiny helper functions.